# Is it possible to update the JTable Entire row at once

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to update the JTable Entire row at once , rather than column wise ??
This is my program below 
Currently i could able to modify column wise only 
using

```
model.setValueAt("1111", 0, 0)
```

Could i use

```
model.setValueAt(new Object[]{"1111","Pavan","Developer"}, 0, 0);


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
public class Preethi {
    protected void initUI() {
        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {
                "Id", "Name", "Desg" }, 0);
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        // table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(Preethi.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Vector vec = new Vector();
        vec.add("1122");
        vec.add("Iraneee");
        vec.add("Dev");
        model.insertRow(0, vec);
        model.setValueAt("1111", 0, 0);
        //model.setValueAt(new Object[]{"1111","Pavan","Developer"}, 0, 0);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Preethi().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: _Update entire row_. So I think delete that row and add new row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) indicate, `setValueAt` sets a single cell value.

> Sets the object value for the cell at column and row. aValue is the new value.

However, you could *overload* the method to handle an `Object` array:

```
class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

   public MyTableModel(Object[] columnNames, int rowCount) {
      super(columnNames, rowCount);
   }

   public void setValueAt(Object[] valueArray, int row) {
      int column = 0;
      for (Object cellValue: valueArray) {
         setValueAt(cellValue, row, column);
         column++;
      }
   }
}
```

Using this model you would then be able to set the values for a given row:

```
model.setValueAt(new Object[] { "1111", "Pavan", "Developer" }, 0);
```

---

**Slightly Shorter Version:**

```
class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

   public MyTableModel(Object[] columnNames, int rowCount) {
      super(columnNames, rowCount);
   }

   public void setValueAt(Object[] valueArray, int row) {

      getDataVector().setElementAt(new Vector(Arrays.asList(valueArray)), row);     
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to use `getDataVector().setValueAt()` and then invoke `fireTableRowsUpdated`.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I've added a table model using `getDataVector` but the `JTable` updates _without_ calling fireTableRowsUpdated.

Comment: @Reimeus +1 for the answer. May be this is due to using _DefaultTableModel_. By default it calls _fireXXXMethods_ when data is changes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to update the JTable Entire row at once , rather than
>   column wise ??

Since you don't want to traverse the entire row. I suggest you to remove that particular row and then add a new row with the updated values using `addRow` method.

OR

If each row in the table is an `Object` then you can get the list the table is using and then remove that from the list and add your new Object to the list.

Comment: Thanks Che , the first approach seems good , but i guess this would be a heavy operation each time .

Comment: @PreethiJain Yep you are right. It was just a suggestion. As _Guillaume Polet_ and _Reimeus_ suggested **getDataVector().setValueAt()** will work great. +1 for the question learnt something today.